# Azure Data Flow not deleting the row in AlterRow

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am not sure what wrong data-flow is not deleting the rows it giving this error " Activity dataflow38 failed: "

In Preview Tab it is showing the rows which i want to delete but it not there is no relationship with the table

[image]

[image]

**error**

```
 "message": "Job 'c688a5bd-34dd-44e2-8292-724f0ea5f98a failed due to reason: DF-EXEC-1 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.\ncom.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:256)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:108)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:28)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.doInsertBulk(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:1611)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.access$200(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:58)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy$1InsertBulk.doExecute(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:709)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.sendBulkLoadBCP(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:739)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.writeToServer(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:1684)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.writeToServer(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:669)\n\tat com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect.DataFrameFunctions.com$microsoft$azure$sqldb$spark$connect$DataFrameFunctions$$bulkCopy(DataFrameFunctions.scala:127)\n\tat com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect.DataFrameFunctions$$anonfun$bulkCopyToSqlDB$1.apply(DataFrameFunctions.scala:72)\n\tat com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect.DataFrameFunctions$$anonfun$bulkCopyToSqlDB$1.apply(DataFrameFunctions.scala:72)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:951)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:951)\n\tat org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2284)\n\tat org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2284)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:139)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)\n\tat org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:497)\n\tat org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1526)\n\tat org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:503)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "dataflow38"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Alter Row delete policy will delete all rows because you are using true() in your expression. Are you sure this is what you want?

This error is likely coming from your Sink field mapping. If you just want to delete rows, then don't set any sink mapping.

Just map your key column. And make sure the data type matches for your key mapping. If it doesn't cast it in a Derived Column.

To make this better, I don't think we should default to auto-mapping if all you're doing is deleting.